# Multi lingual setup for windows application?

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, installation, multilingual

We are developing a windows application in .NET(C#)
IDE used is Visual Studio 2008.

We are using localization to run the program multi lingually.
What we would like to know is how to make the Setup of the windows Application multi-lingual.

ie: When the end users runs the setup, it asks like please select your language.
On selecting say, french, the installation instructions should be displayed in french.
How to do that?

And one more point, we would like to implement this without any third party tools.

Regards,
naveenj

Comment: you are developing a web application or windows application? If its windows application why "ASP.Net"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've mentioned "no third party tools", however, have a look at [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), its **free** and has multi-language support.

Comment: > Its Open Source and it will do.
Thanks a lot